# SQL Query check column values if it's in an Array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

My existing SQL Query:

```
$getEdu = "SELECT * FROM Request_Subject WHERE REQUEST_ID = $id
                                         AND SUBJECT_ID IN (2,3,4)";
```

So in my Database, each `REQUEST_ID` can be associated with multiple `SUBJECT_IDs`

And `SUBJECT_ID` has values ranging from `1 to 10`.

So my existing values in the table are:

```
REQUEST_ID: 1 -> SUBJECT_IDs: 2,3
REQUEST_ID: 2 -> SUBJECT_IDs: 2,4
REQUEST_ID: 3 -> SUBJECT_IDs: 2,8
```

So currently when the query runs, `REQUEST_ID = 3` will still be included in the results because it has the `SUBJECT_ID = 2`.

Is there a possible way for me to create a SQL Query where even if one value matches, the Query would ignore the `REQUEST_ID` because it has different values from the array.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**

Current Results:

```
    $requestSubjects = array();

    // So if I call REQUEST_ID = 3
    $getEdu = "SELECT * FROM Request_Subject WHERE REQUEST_ID = 3
                                             AND SUBJECT_ID IN (2,3,4)";

    $getEdu_answer = mysqli_query($connection, $getEdu);

    if(!$getEdu_answer || mysqli_num_rows($getEdu_answer)==0) {
      echo "Error";
      die();
    }

    else {
      while($subjectRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getEdu_answer)) {
        $subject = $subjectRow["Subject_ID"];

        array_push($requestSubjects, $subject);    
      }

      $reqSub = '{"reqSubject":' .json_encode($requestSubjects). '}';
      echo $reqSub; // Returning a JSON to ajax
    }
```

Echoed Results:

```
{"reqSubject":[2]}
```

The result is correct as the `REQUEST_ID=3` is associated with a `SUBJECT_ID = 2`.

However what I want is that since `REQUEST_ID=3` is also associated with `SUBJECT_ID = 8`, it should not echo a result at all.

Comment: Please, add some more sample data and wanted result.

Comment: what error you have?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have ALL SUBJECT_IDS of a REQUEST_ID to match (2,3,4) and only then to print the result?
if so, you can construct the query for each SUBJECT_ID

**EDIT:**

1. You must get **ALL** SUBJECT_IDs of REQUEST_ID using another sqlquery
2. Contact SUBJECT_IDs to your $getEdu query, and only then execute $getEdu query

Example:

```
$getEdu = "SELECT * FROM Request_Subject WHERE REQUEST_ID = $id";
    //$sub_list is the all subect_id of $id
    foreach ($sub_list as $sub_id){
        $getEdu.=" AND $sub_id IN (2,3,4)";
    }
    $getEdu_answer = mysqli_query($connection, $getEdu);
```

If you execute it on your example, REQUEST_ID =3, 
Than $qetEdu query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM Request_Subject WHERE REQUEST_ID = 3 AND 2 IN (2,3,4) AND 8 IN (2,3,4)
```

meaning that REQUEST_ID = 3 won't return because 8 is not in (2,3,4)

Hope it help a bit.

Comment: Doesn't work. Now it will echo both values: `{"reqSubject":[2, 8]}`

Comment: The query you should receive: SELECT * FROM Request_Subject WHERE REQUEST_ID = 3 AND 2 IN (2,3,4) AND 8 IN (2,3,4) it should return nothing because subject_id 8 is not in (2,3,4)

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
$getEdu = "SELECT * FROM Request_Subject WHERE REQUEST_ID=3
                                             AND SUBJECT_ID IN (2,3,4, if(REQUEST_ID=3,8,null))";
```

if I understand you correctly...